# ajax callback collision in asynchronous mode

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

```
$http({
url: "php/load.php",
method: "GET",
params: {'userId':userId}
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   $scope.data = data;

}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
});

$scope.data[0]= "something";
```

How to wait above ajax to finish loading then load $scope.data[0]= "something";? I tried to place it within the $http and below $scope.data=data but it seem to have collision still..

Comment: why don't just do it inside the success callback?

Comment: -1 Not a real question. [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Simple answer: You can't.

Answer (score 1):

```
var promise1 = $http({
url: "php/load.php",
method: "GET",
async: false,
params: {'userId':userId}
});
$.when(promise1).then(
function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.data = data;
},
function(data, status, headers, config) {
}
).done(function() {
$scope.data[0]= "something";
});
```

Haven't tested, but that should be right. Look into [jQuery.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) and [jQuery.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) if not.